# Who develops glibc , the os kernel programmer?

Tags: glibc

I am really confused about glibc, and I wanna know who develop it.Maybe the os kernel programmer? Or someone else?

Answer (score 0):

> I wanna know who develop it

Here is a [list](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MAINTAINERS).

> Maybe the os kernel programmer? Or someone else?

GLIBC != kernel, so it's not "os kernel programmer". Though GLIBC developers are certainly familiar with kernel interfaces.

Comment: thanks, "os kernel programmer" just developed system call, and GLIBC developers packed that system call with C functions as GLIBC, could I think like this?

Comment: @JasonZhang You could. Just be aware that "packaging kernel interfaces so they are easily callable from `C`" is a tiny part of GLIBC. 99% of GLIBC source has ~nothing to do with the Linux kernel (and is portable to other UNIX OSes).